# VB SQL ACCESS Select Where Like Statement

Tags: sql, vb.net

Net, i'm trying to learn how to display a query result into data grid whenever i click the Search Button as a trigger event for the query. 
But nothing happens when i click the Search Button but gives me an error message (Please see link for the screenshot of error message) which i don't understand.

Error: http://s1.postimg.org/di091riv3/error1.jpg

Can you please point me to the right track, Thanks.

Here is my code below

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class SearchForm
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection



    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Statd.SelectedIndexChanged

    End Sub


    Private Sub SearchButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SearchButton.Click

        con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source= c:\Databse\Company_db.accdb"
        con.Open()


        Dim sqlQuery As String
        Dim sqlCommand As New OleDbCommand
        Dim sqlAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim Table As New DataTable
        Dim empNum As String
        Dim empLname As String
        Dim empDept As String
        Dim empStat As String


        empNum = eNumText.Text
        empLname = empLnameText.Text
        empDept = Deptd.Text
        empStat = Statd.Text

        sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_empinfo WHERE LastName like '% " & empLnameText.Text & "' "

        ' MsgBox("Employee Number " + empNum + empLname + empDept + empStat) 'test statement 


        With sqlCommand
            .CommandText = sqlQuery
            .Connection = con

            With sqlAdapter
                .SelectCommand = sqlCommand
                .Fill(Table)

            End With

            For i = 0 To Table.Rows.Count - 1
                With DataGridView1
                    .Rows.Add(Table.Rows(i)("EmpID"), Table.Rows(i)("FirstName"), Table.Rows(i)("LastName"), Table.Rows(i)("Department"), Table.Rows(i)("Position"), Table.Rows(i)("Status"), Table.Rows(i)("Years"))

                End With
            Next


        End With






        con.Close()
    End Sub
```

Comment: This code will be vulernable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn any suggestion? This code it's not giving me anything but this error http://s1.postimg.org/di091riv3/error1.jpg do i have to change something in properties?

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Private Sub SearchButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SearchButton.Click
    sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_empinfo WHERE LastName like '%' + ? + '%' "

    'It's counter-intuitive, but it's best in .Net to use a new connection object each time
    Using con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source= c:\Databse\Company_db.accdb"), _
          cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlQuery, con)

        'Use actual column type and length here
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = empLnameText.Text

        con.Open()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: i tried to replace my code with yours, and filled the data, however it's flashed me with an empty data grid and gave me the same error http://s1.postimg.org/di091riv3/error1.jpg, Please let me know what i'm doing wrong, Thanks

Comment: If it flashed the grid, then this code probably ran okay, and it's something after this that causes the exception. If the grid is empty, make sure you're searching for something that actually exists. What line is highlighted by visual studio when the exception is thrown?

Comment: I had eliminated the error, it's giving me a blank grid. i tried setting the filter as exactly as what's int textbox, yet it's giving me an empty grid. What could be possibly wrong? Is this parameter wrong? cmd.Parameters.Add("LastName", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = empLnameText.Text
            DataGridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader()

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the `%` to `*` in your query, just like this:

```
sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_empinfo WHERE LastName like '* " & empLnameText.Text & "' "
```

Access doesn't use % as `wildcard`:

http://www.techonthenet.com/access/queries/like.php

Comment: i tried this code http://pastebin.com/16w1dAC0 exactly filtering the search with what's in the textbox it's giving me an error and it's highliting .Fill(Table), i don't really know how to display query result into data grid. Please help

Answer (score 0):

I spotted an error in the usage of %. It is used for SQL Server and Not Access SQL use * in place of %